# Inserting event handler into images using Java GUI

Tags: java, swing, awt, actionlistener

I want to insert an image and then want to add an event to this image using Java GUI. I add the image and then try to insert it into this container but it shows error. Can you please show me which is the right way of inserting an image in Java and then adding a listener to this image or an event handler? Or if using a container to handle the image is the right way. How can I do it?

This is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class Back extends JFrame { 
    private Container pane;
    public Back() {
        super("title");
        setLayout(null);

        Icon i=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("1.png"));
        pane=new Container();

        thehandler hand=new thehandler(); //konstruktori i handler merr 
                                          //nje instance te Background
    }

    private class thehandler implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Back  d = new Back() ;

        d.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        d.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        d.setSize(700,500);

        d.setVisible(true); 
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use a `JLabel` or a `JButton` for the icon, you can also add the listener directly on that component. See [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) for a further explanation.

Comment: Ok is another way for inserting an image without using a JLabel or JButton?

Comment: The only other way I know of is to draw the image (`graphics.drawImage(...)`) inside the `paintComponent` method of for example a `JPanel`. Btw, what I forgot to mention: 1) Please always post the full error message you are getting 2) Make sure the image is actually in the `src` folder of your project

Comment: thehandler (should be TheHandler) must inherits from some JComponent thats, which has [implemented ActionListener in API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/api.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of making a clickable button using a `JButton`

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class GUITemplate {
    JFrame myMainWindow = new JFrame("Title");
    JPanel  firstPanel = new JPanel();

    private void runGUI() {
        myMainWindow.setBounds(10, 10, 400, 400);
        myMainWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        myMainWindow.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
        createFirstPanel();
        myMainWindow.getContentPane().add(firstPanel);
        myMainWindow.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void createFirstPanel() {
        firstPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        ImageIcon image1 = new ImageIcon("YourImage.ImageFileType");
        Image image2 = image1.getImage().getScaledInstance(300,300,0);
        ImageIcon image3 = new ImageIcon(image2);

        JButton jB = new JButton(image3);
        jB.addActionListener(new TheHandler());
        firstPanel.add(jB);
    }

    private class TheHandler implements ActionListener { //Changed thehandler to TheHandler
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) { //because it is a class
            //Do Something
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GUITemplate gt = new GUITemplate();
        gt.runGUI();
    }
}
```

Comment: *"Sorry for using a null layout on panel, just using an old template I found"* - expect to receive no forgiveness as it would not have take much effort to remove it

Comment: @MadProgrammer You really, really hate null layouts don't you?

Comment: I've spent the last 6 years cleaning up the mess of another developer who violated just about every layout rule there is (including using `null` layouts), so yes, I hate `null` layouts. To many inexperienced developers think they know how to deal with `null` layouts without having an understand of the role which the layout management API provides and it is just painful to have to fix all the time

Comment: @MadProgrammer Okay. I can change this

Comment: @MadProgrammer Am I forgiven?

Comment: I'll over look [`Image#getScaledInstance`](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html) and not running the code on the EDT ;)